# PHP : How to call method from other class without inheritance

Tags: php, class, object

I have a little problem here, sorry if asking a dumb question.

so, I have StoreCategories Class which have :

```
    class StoreCategories 
    {
        private $store_category_id;
        private $category;

        public function setStoreCategoryId($store_category_id)
        {
            $this->store_category_id = $store_category_id;
        }

        public function getStoreCategoryId()
        {
            return $this->store_category_id;
        }

        public function setCategory($category)
        {
            $this->category = $category;
        }

        public function getCategory()
        {
            return $this->category;
        }
    }
```

In my index.php I declare the object like this :

```
    $types = array();
    while($stmt->fetch())
    { 

       $type = new StoreCategories();
       $type->setCardId($card_id);
       $type->setStoreCategoryId($store_category_id);
       $type->setCategory($category);
       array_push($types, $type);
    }
```

As you see, I want to set Card ID which is not in the StoreCategories Class..

I have a Card Class like this :

```
    class Card
    {
        private $card_id;


        public function setCardId($card_id)
        {
            $this->card_id = $card_id;
        }

        public function getCardId()
        {
            return $this->card_id;
        }
    }
```

I know I can user `Class Card extends StoreCategories` to get the Card ID, but it's too much risk..
Anyone have the other ways to do it ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Rethink you model once again. Why CardId should be in StoreCategories?

Comment: @u_mulder : I want to display card id in the query, so I should set it too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)

Move common part of the code into new `trait`:

```
trait CardIdTrait {

    private $card_id;


    public function setCardId($card_id)
    {
        $this->card_id = $card_id;
    }

    public function getCardId()
    {
        return $this->card_id;
    }

}
```

And modify `Card` class to:

```
class Card {
    use CardIdTrait;
}
```

and

```
class StoreCategories 
{
    use CardIdTrait;

    private $store_category_id;
    private $category;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: is that same as inheritance ?

Comment: @LazyGuy Read linked documentation.